# How to manipulate certain registers on assembly on PIC (18F452)?

Tags: assembly, pic

I have a register called TEST and I want to invert (toggle?) bits 1 and 2 and also put zero to bits 3 and 4.

I have just started learning assembly and I do not know how to check whether my solution is at all correct, could you please tell me if I am at all on the right track?

Here is my suggestion:

```
movlw B'00000010' ;toggles/inverts the bit 1

xorwf TEST,F

movlw B'00000100' ;toggles/inverts the bit 2

xorwf TEST,F

bsf   TEST, 3, 0 ;Sets the bit 3 to zero

bsf   TEST, 4, 0 ;Sets the bit 4 to zero
```

Answer (score 0):

`BSF` does not clear a bit.

```
movlw B'00000110' ;toggles/inverts the bit 1 and 2
xorwf TEST, F
bcf   TEST, 3     ;put zero to bit 3 
bcf   TEST, 4     ;put zero to bit 4
```

otherwise you could put your bits to zero with `ANDWF` instruction

```
molw   0b11100111   
andwf  TEST, F                ;put bit 3 and 4 to zero
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mike!! Maybe I do have some hope in learning this 

Comment: I am Glad to help. And you had to learn to use the debugger/simulator for the basics.

Comment: Thank you, GJ, but why?

Comment: `F` flag is in use for data destination at `mov, add, sub...` instructions so destination can be `WREG` or file register. `bcf` thirth parameters is in use for bank access. Check data sheet...